# outputting a string to terminal and otherwise in a correct format

Tags: python, string, syntax, output

I have a string which I would like to output to the terminal and subsequently write to a file. I have managed to do this in my code but I wish to change the format of it.

Normally this is what should happen with any print statement:

```
 x = scatter
 print (x)
```

and to the terminal screen it outputs

```
 scatter
```

where as my string is of the following format

```
n = 1
x = 'scatter -n', n
```

printing this statement to terminal gives....

```
('scatter -n', 1)
```

What I would like to do is be able to print a string where it has multiple elements of a string of text, followed by a variable declared earlier in the program like above. I am not sure on how to set the syntax such that the string will appear as follows when I print to terminal:

```
scatter -n 1
```

The text provided here is a smaller example of the full string I need to print. In it I have a large number of variables which are defined in my program but for here I will leave them out on this post as it's mainly a syntax issue that I am stuck on. The full string I need to write is as follows:

```
test = '"scatter -n',n,'-A ',A,' -g ',g,' -t ',stime,' -i "-M',Mbu,' -rm ',rm,' -R ',R,' -v ',vrel,' -t -q',qout,' -a ',aoutu,' -e ',eout,' -r1 ',r1,' -t1 -q ',qin,' -a ',ainu,' -e ',ein,' -r1 ',r1,' -r2 ',r2,'"'
```

How I have formatted the string here is the only way I managed to get it to work properly in the program in it's current iteration.

Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you search a simple: `' '.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])` ? Or, with your example `' '.join(x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = 'scatter -n', n
```

This line in your code is not concatenating, it's packing a tuple. That's why the parentheses are showing up in the output. Besides, you can't concatenate an int type onto a string without casting it first, anyway.

Instead, you can use this format to string cast & concatenate:

```
x = "scatter"
y = "-n"
z = 1
cmd = "{} {} {}".format(x, y, z)
print cmd
```

to print

```
scatter -n 1
```

Comment: This is the solution that I found worked best for what I needed thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you define the sequence as an implicit tuple?

If you want to keep it as a list/tuple/whatever collection, consider this:

```
' '.join([str(i) for i in test])
```

Hint: I used `str()` to account for all non-string values that eventually occur in your list of variables.

Otherwise, you could just use regular string formatting `'%s, ...' % (val, ...)`, if the number of variables is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi do you mean like this?

```
test= test.replace(",", " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(x)
('scatter -n', 1)
```

So that's expected behavior since it declared as tuple of elements in variable x.
And python prints it as is.

```
print(', '.join(str(i) for i in x))
scatter -n, 1
```

You are actually looking for **[`join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=join#string.join)** method.